# Why is there one char missing when I index a Garray?

Tags: arrays, missing-data, glib

I ran this code, which I wrote for a GUI program, and I get a curious error, where one char is always missing sequentially. This code is simplified.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main()
{
    GArray *array = g_array_new(FALSE, FALSE, 1000); /* I create the array */

    int i; /* An iterator used in the for loop. */
    char *question = "What does hypersomatic mean?"; 

    /* The insertion loop. */
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        /* I pass the array along, the data, and the number of elements to insert. */
        array = g_array_append_vals(array, question, 1);
    }

    /* The reading loop */
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        /* I pass along the array, the element type (gchar is correct, I think), and the index of the element. */
        char *what_is_this = &g_array_index(array, gchar, i);
        printf("%s\n", what_is_this);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled this with: `` gcc `pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --libs --cflags` main.c ``.

And here is the output:

What does hypersomatic mean?
hat does hypersomatic mean?
at does hypersomatic mean?
t does does hypersomatic mean?
does hypersomatic mean?
oes hypersomatic mean?
es hypersomatic mean?
s hypersomatic mean?
hypersomatic mean?

What is the meaning of this?

Comment: Why do you pass `1000` to `g_array_new`!? Why do you read `gchar` when you store `char*`?

Comment: Thats the size of every element, I suppose I could use 29 instead. Thats the size of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re creating a `GArray` with each element being 1000 bytes long, but then when you’re reading it you’re telling `g_array_index()` that each element is `sizeof(gchar)` bytes long (i.e. 1 byte long). So `g_array_index()` is returning pointers to bytes 0..10 of the first occurrence of your string in the array data chunk.

If you want to print out the entirety of each element, your code needs to be changed to:

```c
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

typedef gchar my_element[1000];

…

    GArray *array = g_array_new(FALSE, FALSE, sizeof (my_element)); /* I create the array */

…

        char *what_is_this = &g_array_index(array, my_element, i);

…
```

This defines a type for the array elements, so the code can refer to its size consistently.

---

It’s a lot more typical to use variable length strings rather than fixed length ones in modern code. Each of those array elements is 1KB long, even though the string stored in them is only 29 bytes long — so 97% of the allocated memory in each element is being wasted.

Using fixed length strings also raises the possibility of very long strings (greater than 1000 bytes long) overflowing the allocation, which the surrounding code might not be prepared for.

Typically, code which uses GLib will use a `GPtrArray` to store elements which are variable length strings, allocated with something like `g_strdup()` or `g_strdup_printf()`.

You may want to consider changing your code to do something like that. However, I don’t know the full context around what you’re trying to achieve, so this suggestion might not be relevant.

Comment: So, how would I do it then?

Comment: It’s not really clear to me what you’re actually trying to do.

Comment: Like how would I be able to print out the array 10 times (or more), with no characters disappearing at the beginning.

Comment: I’ve edited my answer to show how you can change your code to consistently refer to the elements as 1000 bytes long each.